# How to access hosted WCF webservice with jquery in html

Tags: jquery, wcf, web-services

1.I have a simple `WCF` webservice , say hello method that return string "hello". I have hosted it on a server. Say I can access it as http://demo.test.com/myservice/Service.svc?wsdl.

2.I want to access it through simple html page with `jquery` call.

The problem is that `html` page is not being able to access the service. I haven't added anything on service except whatever comes in default with visual studio 2010. Do I need to add anything on the server side service to access them with `jquery` call? How can I be able to access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is service running on same domain as page with JavaScript code?

If not you need to enable CORS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing to make AJAX requests to other domain